# how and where to define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES in C

Tags: c, boost

I'm trying to compile some C github code for a bitcoin like coin that is quite old (https://github.com/zer-dex-coin/zerdex-core) and I wan't to attempt to define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES as I have seen here:

https://github.com/cygnusxi/CurecoinSource/issues/44

> trourance commented on May 4, 2020
> I've found it. Raspbian buster is using boost 1.67.
> This is due to a change in boost 1.66 as stated here: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html
> For version 1.66 and upward, the following macro has to be defined: BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES

my boost version:

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.67.0.1+b1
```

I think I ether must put it as `#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES` at the top of a file before I do

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

I have tried it in configure.ac and main.h and it has no effect. Where should I define this?

or can it be defined on ./configure as a FLAG, CFLAG, CXXFLAGS?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can add preprocessor flags from the environment in automake projects:

```
CPPFLAGS="-DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES" ./configure
```

By convention CPPFLAGS are included in CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS.

If that doesn't work you can use the switches listed in `./configure --help` instead.